# How can I share (GitHub) my code (R) with sensitive information (passwords)?

Tags: r, github, coding-style, passwords, gitignore

Imagine you are using a package that uses an access token. Maybe one from [rOpenSci](http://ropensci.org/).

My current approach is to source a file at the beginning that is in the `.gitignore`. It, hence, gets ignored and I can share without worries.

```
source("never-commit-password.R")
```

However, there is still a danger that it might be uploaded via `.RData`  because I left it in the workspace.

What is leading practice that trades off convenience with safety?

Comment: Add `.RData`, `.Rhistory` etc to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Or never save your workspace.